# Will this reaction apparatus work (refluxing under inert atmosphere)

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

[image: Reaction Apparatus.]

The nitrogen flow comes from the right side, directly into the flask. Then will go up the condenser and through the bubbler to release pressure. I am worried that my solvent that evaporates when refluxing could be dragged up by the nitrogen and I will lose solvent over time... or will it still condense when it hits the cold water from the condenser and come back down and be able to undergo reflux?

Comment: Looks OK with a gentle flow of nitrogen

Comment: What you really want on top of your condenser in one of these https://www.asynt.com/product/gas-bubblers/